# eval() php получить значение массива

Tags: php, массивы, eval

есть код в базе

```
$conten_tamplate = '
    <h4>Редактирования текстового фрейма</h4> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col l12 standalone-container frame_data" data-type="text" data-id="' . $_in['farme_id'] . '"> 
            <div id="snow-container" class="content_frame">'.$_SESSION['ddata'][$_in['docum_id']]['frames'][$_in['farme_id']]['content_frame'].'</div> 
        </div>
</div>';
```

пробую сделать `eval($code_string);` но работает лишь переменная `$conten_tamplate` и выводит текст без наполнения

т.е. `$_SESSION['ddata'][$_in['docum_id']]['frames'][$_in['farme_id']]['content_frame']` не работает

не работает даже `$_SESSION['ddata']`, но `$_SESSION` работает прекрасно

т.е. насколько я понял `eval()` не может обращаться к значениям массива по ключу

**как собственно быть?**

Comment: Попробуй перед функцией `eval()` выполнить присвоение к новым переменным те значения, которые недоступны внутри eval(), а внутри этой функции обращаться к этим переменным

Comment: данные-то есть 
`print_r($_SESSION['ddata']); // работает
$conten_tamplate = '
<h4>Редактирования текстового фрейма</h4> 
<div class="row">
 <div class="col l12 standalone-container frame_data" data-type="text" data-id="' . $_in['farme_id'] . '"> 
  <div id="snow-container" class="content_frame">'.$_SESSION['ddata'][$_in['docum_id']]['frames'][$_in['farme_id']]['content_frame'].'</div> 
 </div>
</div>'; // есть только html
print_r($_in); // работает
print_r($_in['frame_id']); // работает`

это все что я запихнул в `eval()`

Comment: Пробовал написать функцию, которая находится вне eval(), в которую возвращаешь параметр, например название элементов выборки с сессии, она считывает и возвращает? Это как предположение.

Comment: ну ты пример-то свой пришли.

Вот например так `$array_data_templ = array(
 'frame_id' => $_in['farme_id'],
 'content_frame' => $_SESSION['ddata'][$_in['docum_id']]['frames'][$_in['farme_id']]['content_frame'],
);` не работает

Comment: Запусти код, посмотри что выводится: `eval(print_r($_SESSION))`

Comment: все было проще
у меня там очепятка))))

Comment: `farme_id` ВМЕСТО `frame_id`